# Multiple @ServiceActivator methods with an implicit payload-type-routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dynamic-dispatch

Is there an elegant way to define a single `@MessageEndpoint` bean with multiple `@ServiceActivator` methods (or something like that), where the methods' argument types are implicitly used as a payload-type-filter?

The idea is to have a single service endpoint which can handle different payload types slightly different without much effort by dispatching on the argument type, which alleviates the implementation of additional service methods down the line.

I'm aware of Google Guava's `EventBus`, which dispatches event objects to any registered `@Subscribe` method with a matching argument type. I'm currently using this approach, but I was wondering if this was also (kinda) possible with Spring Integration.

Comment: As of now, you'll need a content-based router. It's not clear that your suggestion is a good general-purpose rule; what if I want messages delivered to multiple endpoints?

Comment: In order to deliver it to multiple endpoints, you simply define multiple endpoints. Nobody is stopping you... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML, a `<service-activator ... ref="foo" />` (with no `method`) will resolve to a method based on payload type as long as there are no ambiguities.

With 4.0 or later, you can use...

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(...)
public MessageHandler foo() {
    ...
}
```

Returning a `ServiceHandlingFactoryBean` with the `targetObject` set to your POJO (again, with no method name).

Note, in this case, you have to set the `outputChannel` on the factory bean (the `outputChannel` attribute on the annotation is ignored).